# Using ng-init to bind a variable to a value in my controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, ng-init

I'm working on an editor page. I receive a Json from my server, that contains:

```
{
    "Q_id": 1,
    "isMultipuleAns": 0,
    "Q_mediaType": "page"
}
```

And I'm trying to put the information in input div (type=text) or textarea div.

```
<textarea 
    type="text" 
    name="question_title" 
    ng-model="question.question_title" 
    ng-init="question.question_title=index"`>
```

and in my controller I have something like this:

```
app.controller("someController",function($scope,$location,$http){
    // some http requests that puts the mentioned jason in $scope.myJson
    $scope.index= $scope.myJson.Q_id;
}
```

And no matter what I try, ng-init only works with a static string. I can't get the real ID to appear on the site. Only gets a blank input field.

I am new to html and or angular... help?

Comment: See the red text here:
"This directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates. There are only a few appropriate uses of ngInit, such as for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below; and for injecting data via server side scripting. Besides these few cases, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope."  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit  Long story short aside from the cases listed (and I'd say just the first) don't use ng-init.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `ng-init` in your input as you did, that because it work at start of your project when your view is coming up.

**so what `ng-init` do for me !?**

> `ng-init` used for calling functions from `controller` **inside** the `view` or set default values for variables (which didn't use as `ng-model`) for example:

```
 var controller = function($scope){
   $scope.makeNewId = function(){
      return 15899933666;
   }
 }
```

in this sample we can call `$scope.makeNewId()` directly in the controller also we can do it when our `view` is compile as `ng-init="makeNewId()"`, and if you attention it work ***on each page reload***

**so what's wrong with my codes!**

in your codes you want to set `ng-model` value with `ng-init`, **completely wrong**

*if you ask why*, that because you use something like this `question.question_title` that means you have a `object` which name is `question`; so i can easily define it in my controller:

```
 var controller = function($scope){
    $scope.question = {
      question_title: $scope.myJson.Q_id
    };
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for somthing like that! it really helps my structure!

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's because you're calling `$scope.index= $scope.myJson.Q_id;` inside async method - and that's when ng-inits already fired (can't tell for sure, as there's not enough code provided).

But overall, you probably could use another way than ng-init, as putting app logic inside view is rather bad practice. Why not:

```
$scope.index= $scope.myJson.Q_id;
$scope.question.question_title= $scope.myJson.Q_id;
```

Alternatively, there are times when you could defer ng-init with ng-if, like:

```
<textarea type="text" name="question_title" ng-model="question.question_title" ng-if="index" ng-init="question.question_title=index">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the ng-init in div tag enclosing your text area like this.

```
<div ng-init="question.question_title=index">
    <textarea type="text" name="question_title" ng-model="question.question_title">
</div>
```

This is supposed to prefill your text area with the data in $scope.question.question_title and make sure in your controller $scope.question is already defined like this.

```
$scope.question = {
   question_title:""
}
```